# Determine if a specific Gutenberg block is used on pages/posts

Tags: widgets, block-editor

So we have built out a Gutenberg block that is `acf_register_block_type` as the name `pardot-form`.

I want to build a widget to basically just display all locations of where that specific block is being used. Is there a way to achieve this and/or are there specific functions from Gutenberg to achieve this?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no built-in way to get all the posts in a site that contain a specific block.

Two potential things you could do:

1. You can use the [`has_block()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_block/) to determine if a specific post has a specific block. (there is also a more accurate [`parse_blocks()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parse_blocks/) available). You could loop over all content and fine posts that contain the block that way (probably not great performance wise).
2. Add a custom post meta filed that you toggle to true when a user adds the block to the post and false when the user removes the block. Then you can use a custom [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to get posts where the meta value is `true`. You can use the `useSelect()` React hook to get all the blocks on each post, and check if any have the block you're looking for. Then use a `useEffect()` hook to update the meta.

Comment: Hey @Phil, thanks for pitching in! I was actually able to get it working and found an accurate way to retrieve the data since all of the other methods didn't work. You can do a `get_posts()` call on the `'s' => '<!-- wp:acf/pardot-form '` query.

Comment: @theMap That's clever! Glad you got it working.

Comment: @theMap post your code as an answer then

Answer (score 2):

Like @Phil mentioned, using `has_block()` works if you are using `acf_register_block_type()` to create your block so long as you preface it with "acf/".  So my block was registered like:

```
 acf_register_block_type(array(
        'name'              => 'my-block-name'
        ...
```

And in my header file, I could check if that was being used on the page/post by:

```
if(has_block('acf/my-block-name')) {
     // DO STUFF
}
```